# VS package deployed not showing up in package load analyzer

Tags: vspackage

I developed a vspackage. To deploy I have followed the steps in the MSDN Walkthrough: Deploying a VSPackage. After following the walkthrough, my package does not show up in the Package Load Analyzer, nor does my package gets initialized.

I am guessing I missed a step, but I do not know what step. I did exactly as MSDN documented. This is a package for VS2008 and I also want to use it for VS 2010, but first I want it to work in VS 2008.

UPDATE
I used the MSI step in MSDN. And now my package shows up in de package load analyzer, but the problem is still that my package only gets loaded if I analyze my package in the load analyzer.

Comment: I solved this by myself. At first I follwoed the xcopy option explained on msdn. But that didn't work. Then I followed the steps for the Installer. That worked, but the Package Load analyzer failed to load the package due to plk verification error, while my plk information was correct. I just used a new guid and plk, that workedn.

regards,
Kishen

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by myself. At first I follwoed the xcopy option explained on msdn. But that didn't work. Then I followed the steps for the Installer. That worked, but the Package Load analyzer failed to load the package due to plk verification error, while my plk information was correct. So I used another guid en therefore generated another plk which worked perfectly. The other problem I described, got solved by using the ProvideAutoLoad attribuet.

regards,
Kishen